# How to get LinkedIn user updates in Windows phone 8 app?

Tags: windows-phone-8, linkedin-api

I am working on wp8 app and getting user authenticated using linkedin account. Once authentication has been done, i want to display user linkedIn updates. How to get the updates?

Answer (score 0):

LinkedIn prefer the developers to use OAuth 2.0 to implement authorization with LinkedIn APIs. Compared to its predecessor, OAuth 1.0a, the protocol is simpler and much easier to implement.

So first of all you use LinkedIn APIs you must register your application with LinkedIn.

Please find the guidelines provided at LinkedIn Developers Site,

For References Please check: [LinkedIn Developers](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/authentication)

If any other helps required regarding this please ask.

Comment: Hi king, i already registered my application with linkedIn and even authentication has comppleted. The only thing i want to get LinkedIn user updates

Comment: I'm using oAuthVersion = "1.0" for authentication

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve the company updates from the `LinkedIn API` have a look at this post:

[Reading LinkedIn Updates](https://developer.linkedin.com/reading-company-shares).

Or else through the following article you'll get to know about accessing the data.

[LinkedIn for WP](http://www.sitepoint.com/linkedin-from-a-windows-phone-app/)

Hope it helps!